# Div with CSS3 Blur Filter Shows Blurred Edges on Transition

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-filters

I'm starting to think this is a bug in Chrome because safari doesn't have problems and I've scoured the SO looking for a solution and haven't come up with one.

The problem is that when applying a css filter blur and then clipping the edges, if you try to transition that div, it will show the blur edge momentarily, even if you've scaled the inner div past the filter blur.

**Check out my example and click the image (look at image edges): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqbmJ**

Any ideas here?

```js
$('#background').on('click', function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('ready');

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#background {
  background-image: url(http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/332/220px-BlurParklife.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  left: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  top: -35px;
  bottom: -35px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#background.ready {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to seperate the filter and the transform by considering a pseudo element. It seems to correctly render in Chrome

```js
$('#background').on('click', function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('ready');

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#background {
  background-image: url(https://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/332/220px-BlurParklife.jpg);
  background-size: 0 0;
  left: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  top: -35px;
  bottom: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#background:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  filter: blur(15px);
}
#background.ready {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Background image `blur` `transition` issue. [Pen is here](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/LYEyYrO). Chrome browser get error in [backface-visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility).

You have to change `#background` property like this.

```
#background {
    background-image:url(https://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/332/220px-BlurParklife.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    left:-35px;
    right:-35px;
    top:-35px;
    bottom:-35px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; /* Before it was transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out */
    transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* You have to remove Backface Visibility from -webkit browser */
}
```

**You have to use CSS Prefixer for support all browser. Code is below.**

```
#background {
    background-attachment: scroll;
     background-color: transparent;
     background-image: url(https://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/332/220px-BlurParklife.jpg);
     background-position: left top;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
             background-size: cover;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
             backface-visibility: hidden;
    left:-35px;
    right:-35px;
    top:-35px;
    bottom:-35px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
}

#background.ready {
   -webkit-transform: scale(2);
   -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
     -o-transform: scale(2);
        transform: scale(2);   
}
```

**Note**: I used `transition` property `transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s` instead of `transform 300ms ease-in-out`. Some times I seen Chrome browser showing blur edge momentarily if use `300ms`. You can use `transform 300ms ease-in-out` if it's right for you.

> Hope this help.

Comment: `transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s` is exactly the same as `transform 300ms ease-in-out`

Comment: `transform 300ms ease-in-out` some times show me chrome browser error in blur edge momentarily. So I add `transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s`.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely see what you mean! Kind of looks that there is a small bug in Chrome. The only thing I could think of is a little hack using media.

```
@media (max-width:55rem) {#background{-webkit-filter: blur(10px);filter: blur(10px);}}
```

This will capture the window resolution at 55em (Based on the page set size) and initiate the css styling within that media bracket.

Also consider using depreciated/non-WebKit styling. Sometimes, I've noticed, that doing that I get better results than mixed ones in my styling.

Hope this helps :)